# How do you create a report in Word (or other documentation software) that is linked directly with Excel 2007 data?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, pdf, microsoft-office, microsoft-excel-2007

I believe my question may be best answered by using Access since that's more what it's made for. However, I don't have a license for Access here at work and trying to get one is pulling teeth.

So I'm curious if there is any way to compile reports with data in an Excel 2007 sheet. The output can be .doc, .docx, .pdf - or anything else if there's a decent piece of free 3rd party software.

This might be easiest solved by just creating another sheet in the same workbook and directly linking to the data I want to display in a report-esque format. But I wanted to see if SU could offer some more creative solutions.

Comment: What is the source of the data? Is it another document or does the data come from a database. If the latter, what sort of database?

Comment: This is data being pulled from an ODBC connection (not MS SQL or PL/SQL though). I have the query set up to pull all of the right data, just would like to be able to present it in a more legible format to give to customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you copy a range of cells to the Clipboard in Excel and then use the **Paste Special** command in Word, you can choose to paste the cells as a "Microsoft Office Excel Worksheet Object".

Choose the **Paste** radio button to embed the object within the Word document, or **Paste link** to insert it as a linked object (i.e., a pointer to the Excel file on disk that gets updated when the Excel file is updated).